# only check one radio button using jquery in asp.net

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have the following grid view.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" BackColor="White"
                BorderColor="#CCCCCC" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="4" DataSourceID="UserModule_allusers"
                ForeColor="Black" GridLines="Horizontal" OnRowDataBound="grvGroups_RowDataBound"
                Width="324px" OnSelectedIndexChanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged">
                <Columns>
                    <asp:TemplateField>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:RadioButton ID="selectRow" GroupName="userSelect" runat="server" />
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Here I am using one radio button to select the row. To select the row I am using the following jquery script.

```
 $('#<%=GridView1.ClientID%>').find('input:radio[id*="selectRow"]').click(function () {
    $('<%=GridView1.ClientID%>').find('input:radio[id*="selectRow"]').attr('checked',false);
                $(this).attr('checked', true);
                var isChecked = $(this).prop("checked");
                var $selectedRow = $(this).parent("td").parent("tr");
                var selectedIndex = $selectedRow[0].rowIndex;
                if (isChecked)
                    $selectedRow.css({
                        "background-color": "DarkSlateBlue",
                        "color": "GhostWhite"
                    });
            });
```

In this script i am trying to un-checking first for all the radio buttons in the grid and checking the present context radio button. All the radio buttons are unchecking but present radio button is not checked. Where i done the mistake.

Comment: Why -1? is it not a good question or not in understandable way? If you give the comment before negative voting i can improve myself. Thanks

Comment: Does your radio buttons need to perform actions on server? Can they be normal html radio buttons? or do you have to access them in server side?

Comment: At this point i didn't implementing the server functionality. As of now i am trying for selecting the row by checking the radio button. After checking it i want to retrieve the values of cells(not yet implemented).

Comment: If your problem is to remove the check from the other radio buttons your problem is the name created by gridview, try simple html button like: <input id="selectRow" Name="selectRow" type="radio" />

Comment: We cannot insert html code into the grid view `itemtemplate`

Comment: it is giving error if i add like that.

Answer (score 0):

try this javascript:

```
$('#<%=GridView1.ClientID%>').find('input:radio[id*="selectRow"]').click(function () {
    $('#<%=GridView1.ClientID%>').find('input:radio[id*="selectRow"]').attr('checked', false).parent("td").parent("tr").css({ "background-color": "white", "color": "black" });
            $(this).attr('checked', true);
            var isChecked = $(this).prop("checked");
            var $selectedRow = $(this).parent("td").parent("tr");
            var selectedIndex = $selectedRow[0].rowIndex;
            if (isChecked)
                $selectedRow.css({
                    "background-color": "DarkSlateBlue",
                    "color": "GhostWhite"
            });
});
```

You add an error in this line:

```
$('<%=GridView1.ClientID%>').find('input:radio[id*="selectRow"]').attr('checked',false);
```

you forgot the # before the gridview ID.

I add code to remove formatting from unselected rows too.

Comment: Oh sorry mistake while copying. but even though if i add the `#` it is behaving like that.

Comment: Isn't this the behaviour you want? select clicked row and deselect the others?

Comment: yeah.. i want to deselect and uncheck the radio button which is previously selected.

Comment: Did you try my code? it's working with me. You just need to change the css of the row for your unselected row.